# Symfony not redirecting after login_check on prod

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.3

Security config as simple as in [FOSUserBundle docs](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md), and login works properly on dev environment, but on prod environment it stuck on `login_check` and nothing happens. Nothing in dev or prod logs.

Symfony 2.3.7

security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
                default_target_path: homepage 
                always_use_default_target_path: true
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

config.yml

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Acme\SomeBundle\Entity\User
```

Comment: is it possible that your "Acme" is part of your dev includes but not part of your production includes?  check your appkernel and your composer.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for this problem.

Fixed with update PHP from 5.3.3 to 5.4.22 (all Optional recommendations should be OK).

Answer (score 0):

Based upon your story, i'd like to guess that you "Acme" is included when you're using dev settings but not when using production settings.  check your AppKernel.php / composer.json

Comment: No, it's included to default config.yml